# How to target the second column of table with the class of selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have problem in my codes,I want to get the value of 2 column table data with the class of (SELECTED).

**First need to click the table row of the first table to get the value and to add the class of selected. my function look like this**.

```
$('#edit_chainingBuild').on('click','tr.clickable-row  td:not(:first-child)',function(e){
           $(this).closest('tr.clickable-row').find('td:not(:first-child)').addClass('selected');
      });
```

Now the first table and the clicked table row has a class of selected, via clicking in my second table I want to determine what is the value of table data has a class of selected.

**Note: I want to get the second column of table with the class of selected of table data.**

Now here in my second function I want to alert the value of class of selected

```
$("table#edit_table_chaining_condiments tr").click(function(e){

          var x = $('table#edit_chainingBuild tbody tr.clickable-row td.clickable-row-condiments.selected td:nth-child(2)').text();


          alert(x);


      });
```

My Html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EditchainingBuilderModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true" data-keyboard="false" data-backdrop="static">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg role="document" style="float:right; height:700px; width:490px; ">
    <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header" style="background: linear-gradient(-30deg, #00e4d0, #5983e8); color:white;">
            <h5 class="modal-title edit_noun_build_item" id="exampleModalLongTitle" style="color:white;"></h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" id="closeBuildChainUpdate" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">

            <div class="container">
                <div class="header" style="text-align: center;">
                    <br>
                    <h3>Build Your Chain Button</h3>    
                    <label>This button will be served as customers menu.</label><br>
                    <i class="fab fa-creative-commons-remix" style="font-size:70px;"></i>
                    <br><br>

                    <input type="hidden" value="" class="edit_hidden_noun_id" name="">
                    <table class="table table-hover" id="edit_chainingBuild">
                        <thead>
                            <tr style="font-size: 15px;">
                                <th scope="col">Qty</th>
                                <th scope="col">Condiments</th>
                                <th scope="col">Price</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody style="font-size:14px;">                 

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="edit_build_success_insert btn btn-primary">Build Done</button>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have output that the table row has highlighted because of added class of selected.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You have to understand how selectors work.

When you have `$("selector1 selector2")`, jQuery looks for a `selector2` that is a child of `selector1`.

In your very long one here, looking near the end of it:

```
$('table#edit_chainingBuild tbody tr.clickable-row td.clickable-row-condiments.selected td:nth-child(2)')
```

jQuery is looking for a `td` that is second child of a `td` with classes `clickable-row-condiments` and `selected`...

See the mistake? *(Except if you have some `td` inside another `td`... Which would be invalid.)*

So try to reduce the thing a bit... You are too specific and it leads to errors because it hard to read. You don't necessarily have to list all the ancestors..  Start by targeting the selected elements:

```
$('#edit_chainingBuild .selected')
```

You know there is two `selected` elements here... Use [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) like this to target the right one:

```
$('#edit_chainingBuild .selected').eq(1) // That is zero-based!
```

Then, you can use `.text()`.

Good luck!